# Problematic formula with Apache POI

Tags: excel, groovy, apache-poi

I'm using Java and generating an Excel file via Apache POI.

The following formula works perfect.

```
cell4.setCellFormula('(J' + (itemCountSize + 3) + '-H' + (itemCountSize + 3)+ ')')
```

Now I simply want to divide by the same H value eg. (J50-H50)/H50

```
cell4.setCellFormula('(J' + (itemCountSize + 3) + '-H' + (itemCountSize + 3)+ ')'+ '/H' + (itemCountSize + 3))
```

However it still just gives me (J50-H50)...

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: This is not default Java. In default Java we always use 'single quotes' for char literals and "double quotes" for String literals. So even your first example would not compile.

Comment: You're correct, sorry I'm actually using groovy.

Comment: Have you tried: `cell4.setCellFormula('((J' + (itemCountSize + 3) + '-H' + (itemCountSize + 3)+ ')'+ '/H' + (itemCountSize + 3) + ')')`

Comment: Or, simplifying with groovy string templating: `cell4.cellFormula = "((J${itemCountSize+3}-H${itemCountSize+3})/H${itemCountSize+3})" `

Comment: @tim_yates  - thanks a lot, both of them worked great! Looks much better when you simplify with groovy string templating. Will try to do the same with the rest of my calculations now.

Comment: Cool, added as an answer :-)

Answer (score 1):

Think you need an extra enclosing bracket

Have you tried:

```
cell4.setCellFormula('((J' + (itemCountSize + 3) + '-H' + (itemCountSize + 3)+ ')'+ '/H' + (itemCountSize + 3) + ')')
```

Or, simplifying with groovy string templating:

```
cell4.cellFormula = "((J${itemCountSize+3}-H${itemCountSize+3})/H${itemCountSize+3})" –
```